# Text underline and align Center

Tags: html, css

I would like following text to be underlined and Center align.Here what i tried
but couldnt able to find solution.

```
<p style="border-bottom:thick dashed #F00">Hi Friends </p>
```

I tried with  paragraph tag

I need text to be underlined, not dot or dashed and center aligned

Answer (score 5):

```
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
```

Comment: Here what i tried with. wouter thanks,text is center aligned but not able to get line instead of dot line
p style="border-bottom:thick dashed #F00;text-align: center;
 text-decoration: underlined;"

Comment: Should be "text-decoration: underline;" not "underlined"